# Read php source from another php script

Tags: php, curl, fopen

I have two files reader.php and somesource.php. Both in the same folder.

somesource.php content inside the php tag.

```
echo "hello World";
```

reader.php contents

```
$fp = fopen('somesource.php','r') or die($php_errormsg);
$string = fread($fp,filesize('somesource.php'));
echo $string."<br>";
```

I am expecting to output

```
echo "hello World";
```

But I am seeing a blank page. I even tried. curl and file_get_contents. Both with the same output. If I write anything outside the php tag wil be echoed as normal. anything inside the php tag is skipped.

Please Help

Comment: You likely have an error somewhere.  What's in your error log?

Comment: View the source of the page. You'll probably see the `<?php` opening tag in there. The sequence `<?` in HTML is treated as special content, not as plain text (specifically, a *processing instruction*).

Comment: try this link first http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_show_source.asp

Comment: Why not use [highlight_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php) instead?

Comment: You can do an include to get code evaluated in the file. This works if you want to execute all statements in the somesource-file. it does't work if you intend to do some postprocessing before execution. see include details at http://php.net/manual/de/function.include.php

Answer (score 1):

use

`echo htmlspecialchars($string)."<br>";`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your server setup it may not read it without `<?php echo $stuff; ?>` in there. `<?` aka short tags can break a lot of stuff in my experience.